# Interswitch Payment dependency issue

Tags: android

I have downloaded the Interswitch source code from [here](https://github.com/techquest/isw-payment-sdk-android/releases).

```
v0.0.8-alpha: Merge pull request #27 from techquest/babajide_dev.
```

While I execute this,I am receiving the error message even in default pack. In official site they instructed us to use the following dependencies.

```
repositories {
            maven {
                url  'http://dl.bintray.com/techquest/maven-repo'
            }
        }
        dependencies{
            compile 'com.interswitchng:payment-android:0.0.6'
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
            compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
        }
```

Even I used in my current code and instead of this  compile `'com.interswitchng:payment-android:0.0.6'` default interswith SDK has the follwing `compile 'com.interswitchng:payment-android:0.0.12-Beta'` . While I changed & executed the **updated dependency of Interswitch** I am getting the error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have followed the [steps](https://github.com/techquest/isw-payment-sdk-android#-creating-a-project-and-adding-library-using-android-studio) listed on their Git Repo to the latter.

I'd recommend creating a  new project and testing this.